# Loading in an Image Ranomizer API within javascript to display on an HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, dom

I'm very new to programming.

I'm working on a school project, and I was given an API that displays random dogs each time the web browser is refreshed. For whatever reason I'm getting a 404 error, but I can see the url changing along with the dog breed within the console. On my HTML page I get the broken image icon where the photo is suppose to load in.

Here is my code:

```
let xhrdog = new XMLHttpRequest();   //first ajax request, dog photos from api
xhrdog.onreadystatechange = function() {

  if (xhrdog.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhrdog.status === 200) {
      let ajdog = JSON.parse(xhrdog.responseText); 
      let image = document.createElement('img')
      image.src = ajdog   //xhrdog.responseText;
      let dog = document.getElementById('dog')
      dog.appendChild(image);
    }
  }
}

xhrdog.open('GET', 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random');
xhrdog.send();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very nearly there. It is just that, as you had spotted in the console, you are getting more than the img url back from the service. It is sending a string which you can parse as JSON, as you are doing.

When you have parsed it you actually have an object, not just a single string, in ajdog. One item in that is 'message' and that holds the full url of the dog image. So use ajdog.message rather than just ajdog to put in your img.src.

Here's the snippet with this change:

```js
let xhrdog = new XMLHttpRequest(); //first ajax request, dog photos from api

xhrdog.onreadystatechange = function () {

if (xhrdog.readyState === 4) {

if (xhrdog.status === 200) {

let ajdog = JSON.parse(xhrdog.responseText);
console.log(xhrdog.responseText);//LOOK IN THE CONSOLE TO SEE WHAT IS SENT
let image = document.createElement('img');

image.src = ajdog.message;   //xhrdog.responseText;

let dog = document.getElementById('dog');

dog.appendChild(image);

}
}

}

xhrdog.open('GET', 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random');

xhrdog.send();
```

```html
<div id="dog"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <img src="" alt="">
    <script>
        //https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random
        async function randomDog(){
            //store the promise with url
            const result = await fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random').then((data)=>{
                return data.json()
            })
            //return a object
           return result
        }
        //instanstiate image 
        const img= document.querySelector('img')
        //this function is returning a promise 
        randomDog().then((data)=>{
            //console.log(data)
            img.setAttribute('src',data.message)
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is  a sample of how to get the random picture from url and add it in your 'img' tag's attribute 'src'..The function will return a promise so you need to handle it with (.then) method. hope you will understand.